# Can we type Young Tableaux on this site?

Tags: support, mathjax

Can we type Young Tableaux on this site? If yes, how?

Comment: Duplicate on SO, but not answered: http://stackoverflow.com/q/30957637. It's [not as simple as importing the package](http://stackoverflow.com/q/21192606).

Comment: FWIW,  a low-tech simple (but admittedly not ideal) solution using only basic MathJax is sketched in my Phys.SE answer [here](http://physics.stackexchange.com/a/104841/2451).

Answer (score 1):

I'd guess only something like the following (see [the question about making tables in MarkDown](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/73566/)), since MathJax doesn't support ytableau or any other non-math-mode packages:

<kbd>1</kbd>  <kbd>2</kbd>  <kbd>4</kbd>  <kbd>7</kbd>  <kbd>8</kbd> 
 <kbd>3</kbd>  <kbd>5</kbd>  <kbd>6</kbd>  <kbd>9</kbd> 
<kbd>10</kbd>

This of course looks ugly, the code for it is even uglier, but the only alternative is ASCII/Unicode-tables.

```
╭──┬──┬──┬──┬──┐
│ 1│ 2│ 4│ 7│ 8│
├──┼──┼──┼──┼──┘
│ 3│ 5│ 6│ 9│
├──┼──┴──┴──┘
│10│
└──┘
```

or images

[image: sample Young tableaux]

We can make some tables with MathJax, but I'm not sure how to remove edges, so you're left with something like this:
$$
\begin{array} {|r|r|}
\hline
1&2&4&7&8\\
\hline
3&5&6&9 \\
\hline
10&\\
\hline
\end{array}
$$